# How to transform a JSON message in XML in WSO2

Tags: json, xml, wso2

I am relative new in WSO2 services in Java EE. I started by the Tutorial, but i had some little difficulties because my lack of knowledge about services in general.
My problem now is that i am trying to send a JSON message and receive the same message in XML format. I studied in the site and they talk about Formatter and Builder, but i had a lot of difficult to apply that in my project.
I already tried with Data Mapper, putting him before the send in the return, but this always return the timeout message. And i tried with Payload Factory too, but i thinking that i am doing something wrong, because the same happens.
Someone know a tutorial or good video detailed to i be able to learn how to solve this problem?

If someone could help me i would stay quiet grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xml to json conversion in wso2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452167/xml-to-json-conversion-in-wso2)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i hope you are expected to transform JSON to XML.

[image]

In order to achieve this, you can simply create an API like below

```html
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="JsonToXmlApi" context="/Test">
   <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/xml/">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
         <header name="To" action="remove"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Ok Rajjaz, thank you for your help, i will try here and once that worked out, i will end the ask. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just one more question Rajjaz, i would be able to use this code in a Rest API project, or i should use it in some proxy service, like i saw in another tutorials?

Comment: Hi, You can use in both ways
you can use it as rest API and can call the API in the middle of proxy or you can copy the code and the paste in the proxy where you want to convert the JSON to XML.

Comment: Thank you Rajjaz. I was reading in the documentation of wso2 about the 'messagetype' property name, and i had a doubt, to convert CSV to XML or JSON, i just need use the application/xml, or application/json? Is simple like that or i need to do that in other way?

Comment: Thank you Rajjaz. I will end the question.