# JSON TO XML and XML to JSON conversion in WSO2 EI

Tags: json, xml, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Im completely new to wso2 EI STUDIO and I got a exercise to complete, ie XML to JSON & JSON to XML CONVERSION IN WSO2 EI . someone please help me with this. high priority.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options for the conversion. Depending on your requirement select the appropriate method.

- Using property mediator [1], [4]
- Using Payload factory mediator [2]
- JSON Transform Mediator [3]

[1] - https://medium.com/@pubududp/wso2-esb-how-to-transform-a-json-message-to-xml-in-wso2-esb-rest-api-fc1c204a3205

[2] - [xml to json conversion in wso2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452167/xml-to-json-conversion-in-wso2)

[3] - https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/json-Transform-Mediator/

[4] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-messageType

Answer (score 0):

for transformation try to use

```
<property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

docs: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-messageType